# Scrolling to bottom of tableView programatically when uibutton is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When my View (containing a Table View) loads, I want it to scroll to the bottom of the table view. This works great. However, when one of my buttons (sendReply) is tapped, I also want the tableView to scroll to the bottom. For some reason, scrolling to the bottom of the tableView works when the View is initially loaded, however [self bottomScroll:self] doesn't seem to fire when I place it inside of my sendReply action?

**.m**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

            [super viewDidAppear:animated];

            [self bottomScroll:self];

          }

 - (void)bottomScroll:(id)sender {

            if (self.messages.count > 0)
                [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.messages.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

        }


    - (IBAction)sendReply:(id)sender {

            [self bottomScroll:self];  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Are you sure `messages.count` is greater than 0 when you tap the button? You can set a breakpoint at that line and see if this code is executed.

Also you can try `-scrollRectToVisible` as an alternative.

Comment: messages.count is definitely greater than 0 when the button is tapped - and the breakpoint seems to show that the code is executed. Super strange.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on a clean project? I did what you are trying on a new project and it seems to work fine. The last problem I could think of is the `section:0` part of your indexPath. Are you sure this is also correct?

Answer (score 0):

as phi stated scrollRectToVisible would be the way I would go.  Call your tableView's scroll view passing in the rect of your button you want to show.  It's been awhile since I've used obj-c but:

```
-(IBAction)sendReply: (id)sender {
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible: sendReply.frame, animated: YES]
}
```

? The syntax may be wrong there but it should be close enough to get you where you are going.

In swift:

```
@IBAction func sendReply(sender: UIButton/AnyObject) -> Void {
    let scrollView = tableView.scrollView
    scrollView.scrollrectToVisible(_ rect: sender.frame, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - scrollView isn't declared in the .h file - only UITableView? Am I missing something? E.g. when I drop the above code in, it says scrollView isn't declared (which, makes sense no)?

Comment: let scrollView = tableView.scrollView doesn't exist. Since a UITableView inherits from UIScrollView you have already this method

Comment: Sorry for making this confusing, I was just giving pseudo code to give you the idea of referencing the scrollView inside of your tableView

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange based on your description. Need more code to find whats going on. What can be inferred is you want to scroll the last cell to the bottom. So make sure the contentsize of tableview is larger than its frame vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height){

        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height);
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:point];
}
```